# Proving algebras are closed under set difference

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Using De Morgans rule I can easily prove $E\cap F$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}$. This is done by applying the following definition and the three axioms.

Definition: Let $X$ be some set. An algebra of subsets of $X$, $\mathcal{A}$, is a collection of subsets of $X$ which satisfy the following three axioms;

1. $X \in \mathcal{A}$
2. If $E \in \mathcal{A}$ then $E^c \in \mathcal{A}$
3. If $E, F \in \mathcal{A}$ then $E \cup F \in \mathcal{A}$

However my question is can these axioms be used to show if $E, F\in \mathcal{A}$ then $E\setminus F \in \mathcal{A}$ ?

Comment: $E \setminus A = E \cap A^c$.

Comment: It is good that you attempted to format your math, but you are using unicode to do it.  It is highly preferred that you use MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  [Visit this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more information on how to use MathJax on this and other sites.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay thank you I will look into this!

Comment: @Bungo could you expand on this please?

Comment: @BeccaBee What needs expansion? The equality I stated, or understanding how to apply it?

Comment: Understanding how it's applied if possible. I understand what you've stated.@Bungo

Comment: As an aside, your first axiom can be relaxed and replaced simply by $\mathcal{A}$ is nonempty.  This, coupled with your second and third axioms together imply that $X\in\mathcal{A}$ by noting that $E\cup E^c = X$.

Comment: @BeccaBee In your first sentence, you said that you've established that $\mathcal A$ is closed under pairwise intersection. And axiom 2 tells you that $\mathcal A$ is closed under taking complements. These are the only operations used in forming $E \setminus F = E \cap F^c$.

Comment: @Bungo Oh okay I understand now, thank you!

Comment: @JMoravitz Never thought of simplifying the axiom. It's a nice move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $E$ and $F$ are both elements of $\mathcal{A}$

Since $E$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complementation, it follows that $E^c$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

Further, since $E^c$ and $F$ are both elements of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under union, it follows that $(E^c\cup F)$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

Finally, noting that $(E^c\cup F)$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}$ and that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complementation, it follows that $(E^c\cup F)^c$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

Then noting that: $E\setminus F = E\cap F^c = (E^c\cup F)^c$, it follows that $E\setminus F$ is an element of $\mathcal{A}$ and therefore $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under set differences.

Comment: Thank you! I think the concept of closed is something I need to work on. Makes sense once I see the steps.